Can we relax the assumptions and still get a.s. convergence?

Assume you have a sequence of independent Bernoulli random variables
$X_i$ each with probability $p_i$. Let $c_i$ be a sequence of real numbers and $ m$ be a real numbers such that $c_1>0$ and
with $0 \le m <c_i< \infty $. Define
$$Y_n=\frac{\sum\limits_{i=1}^n c_i X_i -\sum\limits_{i=1}^n c_i
 p_i}{\sum\limits_{i=1}^n c_i}.$$
Then $Y_n$ converges a.s to zero. (Proof below).

Questions:

Is my proof correct?

Does the result also hold with $m= 0$?


Proof:
Define $$Z_i = c_i (X_i-p_i).$$ Then $E[z_i]=0$. By the strong law of large numbers we have that $\bar{Z_n} \rightarrow 0$ a.s. We also have $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n c_i > m\cdot n$, so we have $n< \sum\limits_{i=1}^n c_i/m$. Hence we have
$$|Y_n| =\left| \frac{\sum\limits_{i=1}^n Z_i }{\sum\limits_{i=1}^n c_i }\right| =\frac{n}{\sum\limits_{i=1}^n c_i }\cdot |\bar{Z_n}|<\frac{1}{m}\cdot |\bar{Z_n}| ,$$
and the last quantity goes to zero a.s.

Does your $Z_i$'s satisfy the IID condition (which is crucial for SLLN to be applicable)?

As for you second question, consider $p_i=\frac{1}{2}$ and $c_i=\frac{1}{2^i}$. Then $Y_n$ converges to the RV which has the uniform distribution on $[-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}]$.

@SangchulLee Thank you, I see I have made some mistakes.

@SangchulLee Could you please give some hints to the proof of the convergence to the uniform distribution?

as to your "m=0" problem, you can remove any zero $c_i$ in the sum, so I'd say yes, no problem with $m=0$ as long as at least one of the $c_i$ is nonzero.

TLDR: $c_i = 10^{i}$ is a counter-example; you can't apply SLLN directly; below, I apply Markov's inequality instead.
Consider the unnormalized variable: $S_n = \sum c_i (X_i - p_i)$

Observe that $t \rightarrow |t|^{1+a}$ is convex. By jensen's inequality
$$
E( |S_n|^{1+a} ) \leq E \sum_i c_i^{1+a} |X_i - p_i|^{1+a} \leq \sum_i c_i^{1+a}
$$

Normalizing by $\sum c_i$ to recover $Y_n$:
$$
E |Y_n|^{1+a} \leq \frac{\sum_i c_i^{1+a}}{(\sum c_i)^{1+a}}
$$

If we can prove that this limit goes to 0, then we can apply Markov's inequality to conclude.


Now returning to your questions and conditions:

Your condition is insufficient for convergence because the sum could be dominated by a single $c_i$ that is much larger than the other ones. In that case, $Y_n$ behaves like the bernoulli of that coefficient. For example, consider $c_i = 10^{i}$. If we consider that the $c_i$ are bounded above and below, then convergence is ensured via my proof.

We do not need the $c_i$ to be bounded below, but we need that their sum is not too close to 0 so that the normalization term grows sufficiently fast.

I have removed the $p_i$ from my bound but that's very brutal. A large $c_i$ can be countered by a very small $p_i$ (or $(1-p_i)$).


NB: my proof only gives a sufficient condition, not a sufficient and necessary one. I'm really unsure how to obtain a necessary condition here.
